# What is the dart equivalent of a php associative array, and how to store it in Firestore?

Tags: dart

I had a stable relationship with [php associative arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)  :)

eg

```
$assocArr = [
"title1" => ["haha", "hehe"],
"huhuh3" => ["hihihi" , huhuhu"]
];
```

What would be the equivalent in Dart? Ideally, class based so we can use the benefits of IDEs like Android Studio. Also, how would we store such classes in Firestore?

Comment: A `Map<Key, Value>` in dart is similar to the requirements mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no experience with PHP associative arrays but from your example it looks like what you want is a [`Map`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Map-class.html):

```
void main() {
  Map<String, List<String>> assocArr = {
    'title1': ['haha', 'hehe'],
    'huhuh3': ['hihihi', 'huhuhu']
  };
  print(assocArr); // {title1: [haha, hehe], huhuh3: [hihihi, huhuhu]}
  print(assocArr['title1']); // [haha, hehe]
}
```